# How to connect external service from docker service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am a newbie to docker. I am running Postgresql running on my local machine (i.e. On Mac OS). My application is running in docker. What I want is my application should be able to access PostgreSQL (has got a lot of production data, which can't be run on docker) service from docker. How to do it? Could anyone give me an example of doing so?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Yes. I got it. @tgogos

Comment: Then, It will be ok if you post an answer to your own question and accept it (for future users). More at: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to link external services inside docker. Added below lines in the `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
    extra_hosts:
       my-local-host: 10.0.0.10 #Local machine IP
     environment:
       - SERVER=http://my-local-host:3000
```

Comment: Is this docker-compose thing or is this compatible with Docker Swarm ?

Comment: above snippet for `docker-compose.yaml`.  @Vinigas

Comment: wish this was more detailed

Answer (score 2):

At my case (I have docker running on Ubuntu) there is a `docker0` network interface and the host takes the IP `172.17.0.1`. Every container that will attach to the *default network* will get an IP within the `172.17.0.X` range. This way, containers can access services running on the host by talking to `172.17.0.1[:port]` because they're on the same network...

But, things are different for Docker for Mac...

From: [Networking features in Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds)

> ## Known limitations, use cases, and workarounds
>
> Following is a summary of current limitations on the Docker for Mac networking stack, along with some ideas for workarounds.
>   There is no `docker0` bridge on macOS
>
> Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker for Mac, you cannot see a `docker0` interface in macOS. This interface is actually within `HyperKit`.
>
> ### Use cases and workarounds
>
> #### I want to connect from a container to a service on the host
>
> The Mac has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From `17.12` onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special Mac-only DNS name `docker.for.mac.host.internal`, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that you can run your app in the `host` network. For example in your compose file, under the service, set `network-mode: host`. Intead of creating a network the container app will join the local machine network, so all services can talk without port mapping.

```
services:
  my_app:
    build: .
    image: my_app:latest
    network_mode: host
```