# IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler[7] .Bearer was not authenticated

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

**When i run this Asp.Net core webapi using iis express, it's running fine. But if i run this same project using docker container, the error shown: bearer was challenged.**

IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler[12]
iam                        |       AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
iam                        | info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
iam                        |       Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
iam                        | info: IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator[0]
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
iam                        |       Exception occurred while processing message.
iam                        |       System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:8081/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
iam                        |        ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:8081/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
iam                        |        ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (localhost:8081)
iam                        |        ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
iam                        |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken) iam                        |          --- End of inner exception stack trace --- iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
iam                        |          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
iam                       |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
iam                      |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
iam                        |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) iam                      |          --- End of inner exception stack trace --- iam                       |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
iam                        |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
iam                        | fail: IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler[0]
iam                       |       IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:8081/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
iam                        |       System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:8081/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
iam                       |        ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:8081/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
iam                       |        ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (localhost:8081)
iam                        |        ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
iam                        |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken) iam                        |          --- End of inner exception stack trace --- iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
iam                        |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
iam                        |          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
iam                        |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
iam                        |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
iam                        |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) iam                        |          --- End of inner exception stack trace --- iam                        |          at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
iam                        |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
iam                        |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
iam                        |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
iam                        |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
iam                        |          at IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
iam                        | info: IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler[7]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use https://localhost:8081 inside the container, you need to configure the URL to your IdentityServer so its reachable from within the container. I assume you have your IdentityServer on a separate service outside the container.

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148920/how-to-connect-external-service-from-docker-service) and this link:

- [How to Connect to Localhost from within a Docker Container](https://zpz.github.io/blog/connect-to-localhost-from-container/)

Comment: I tried this, but still same issues. I can access the /connect/token. after that when i send any request. cannot get any responses. the error shows as follows above.

Comment: You can login interactively into your container https://techeplanet.com/login-to-docker-container/ and then use curl to try to make requests to your discovery endpoint and to debug your network problems.